# git pull deleting commits

Tags: git, version-control

I have a case where `git pull` is deleting my commits. Here's how to easily reproduce the case:

1. the local branch has one commit that puts it ahead of the remote tracking branch
2. `git push`
3. on the **remote repo** a `git update-ref -d refs/heads/<branch> <branch>~1` is done. Yeah, I know...please don't ask why or don't just say that I shouldn't be doing this. It has to do with some backend automation which could put this thread way off topic. Anyway...
4. back in the local repo, `git pull`
5. leading commit has disappeared

Basically what's happening is that I have `branch.<branch name>.rebase` set to true, and on this rebase step it's defaulting to the semantics of `--fork-point` which (I think) basically iterates down from the top of the local branch's reflog and checks to see if the SHA exists in the remote tracking branch's reflog. Once it exists in both, that's the fork point. In this little corner case, however, it's ***not*** the actual fork point. The correct fork point is actually returned if the remote tracking branch and the local branch arguments are swapped on the command line.

1. Is it possible to set `--no-fork-point` to be the default for rebasing? I looked at the [git config documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) and couldn't find anything obvious that would turn `--fork-point` off
2. I tried using git aliasing, but it's awkward and requires everyone to use unconventional commands

Comment: AFAIK doing any sort of `git pull` cannot result in commits being deleted.  In the most extreme case, `git pull --rebase` would result in some of your commits being _rewritten_ and played on top of some stuff on the remote, but even in this case they would not be getting deleted.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: alas, when `git pull` runs `git rebase` (as it does if you have `branch.<whatever>.rebase` set to `true`), you get the fork-point code.

Comment: @torek I am totally unaware that this can happen.  Maybe add some info to your answer if you feel like it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah, that's what I originally thought too. Have you tried the reproduction steps above? What you said is true with the exception of if you do an update-ref in the remote repo and then pull down, which is of course not at all a common scenario since it changes history similar to a forced push. Again, I'd rather not get into the details of why an update-ref shouldn't be happening at the remote.

Comment: @solstice333 The key thing you said is that history is changing on the remote.  If not for this, I believe my original comment would be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That, unfortunately, is the actual goal of `--fork-point`: it's meant to strip out upstream commits that the upstream itself stripped out, that you have in your branch.

The answer to Q1 is that there is no way to turn this off from `git pull`.  Normally I advise against `git pull` anyway: use `git fetch` followed by `git rebase` ... but the default `--fork-point` that you get if you don't specify a particular upstream (or `--root`) will *still* bite you here.

Q2 is not really a question: aliasing is a bit awkward, yes.  An explicit `git fetch` followed by `git rebase --no-fork-point` will do the job, but it requires that people actually do that.